# How to center code in Zen mode in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When entering the zen mode in Intellij Idea the code is aligned to the left which makes you turn your neck/eyes slightly in the same direction. Is there a way to center code like on the screenshot? I use **2022.3.3** version.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max editor's width in Zen mode depends on hard wrap under "Preferences | Editor | Code Style | General":
[image]